# Python appending an array to an opened file

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Im trying to append  512x512 arrays to  files in a calculation process. The data are too huge to store them in the memory so I want to append the array to the file. There a multiple files which has to be extended. Here is my approach in a small example:

```
import numpy as np 
array1 = np.random.rand(512,512)
array2 = np.random.rand(512,512)
arrayList = [array1,array2]

for number,i in enumerate(arrayList):
    with open('path', 'ab') as f:
        np.save(f, arrayList[number])
arrayTest = np.load('path')
```

The files are getting bigger so I think the arrays are appended but if I load them there is only one array inside. I think the arrays are not stacked in the right way and np load just recognizes the first array when loading it.

Comment: first, there's a typo in your `open`, a closing parenthesis too much, then, why aren't u opening this file and turning in into an np array before editing it ? Because for now, it's just appending the lists as strings

Comment: Your guess is correct, the NumPy serialization format does not support multiple arrays in one file. You can use [`np.savez`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savez.html) to save multiple arrays in one zipped file, but I think you cannot append arrays to an existing file (through NumPy I mean, maybe you could with [`zipfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html)). You can use [`np.memmap`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html) to create a huge disk-backed array.

Comment: (also, there's now 2 closing parenthesis too much in the `open` after the edit. Correct is : `open('path', 'ab')`)

Comment: @jdehesa Thank you, I think that is exactly what I need with the np.memmap

Comment: You have to use repeated loads on an open file to fetch all you saved.

Comment: @hpaulj What do you mean with that for example?

Comment: uae load in the same way you used save

Comment: @hpaulj ahh ok! Thank you